# finding generic Quantum circuits for k-local hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Let $P_n$ denote the Pauli group on $n$ qubits (think of n as a large number).

Let 
$G=\left<g_1,...,g_n\right> < P_n$ be some abelian subgroup such that each $g_i$ acts on at most $k\ll n$ qubits. Assume that $g_i$ are independent and $-I\notin G$.

- Does there always exist some unitary $U$ such that $U^\dagger G U=\left<X_1,...,X_n\right>$?
- If so, what does $U$ look like? Can we ensure $U$ is "simple" enough? More precisely, can we find such a $U$ when we restrict ourselves to constant depth unitary quantum circuits?

Answer (score 1):

Any set of commuting stabilizers can be mapped to any other set of commuting stabilizers by applying a unitary from the Clifford group, see http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807006.

The Clifford group is generated by CNOT, Hadamard, and the phase gate $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\&i\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, so your $U$'s indeed have a special form.

However, $U$ can't always be chosen to be local.  Consider, e.g., the [Toric Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_code) on a sphere: It is given by $n$ local and commuting stabilizers, and its ground state (=the joint $+1$ eigenstate of all stabilizers) has global (topological) entanglement, and thus cannot be converted to a product state with constant depth circuits.

Comment: The thing is: you can NOT express any of the globally entangled ground states of the toric code with n independant AND local constraints: 
If the code is on $n^2$ qubits, then you can describe it's ground space as the stabilized space of at most $n^2-2$ local constraints.
Here it's not the case as the stabilized space is unique since we have n commuting pauli elements, and therefore, there is no global entanglement involved.

Comment: Although the toric code itself is irrelevant, the spherical "code" (it's not really a code but it's still well defined) looks like the perfect candidate for my question, as it can be described as the unique stabilized space of n local Pauli  constraints (stars and plaquettes on some tessellation of the sphere)

Comment: @user3001348 That's why I took a toric code on a sphere -- while it is indeed not a code, it still has topological entanglement.

Comment: Oups, I missed the sphere part :)

Anyways, how do you prove that this state can't be constructed with some local depth circuit? The only proof I know of involves global entanglement wich requires a degenerate ground space

Comment: @user3001348 This might take some thought, but I'm sure it'll work out. After all, the state on any subregion of the sphere is no diffent from a contractible region of the toric code state on the torus and, e.g., there is a topological correction to the entanglement entropy.

Comment: @user3001348 Would you be happy with spatially local constant-depth circuits?

Comment: I can already prove the spatially local case. I am struggling to prove the general one.